# word in words.words() check too slow and inaccurate in Python

Tags: python, collections, nlp, nltk, stemming

I am having a dataset, which is consisting of two columns, one is a Myers-Briggs personality type and the other one is containing the last 50 tweets of that person. I have tokenized, removed the URLs and the stop words from the list, and lemmatized the words.

I am then creating a `collections.Counter` of the most common words and I am checking whether they are valid English words with `nltk`.

The problem is that checking if the word exists in the corpora vocabulary takes too much time and I also think that a lot of words are missing from this vocabulary. This is my code:

```
import nltk    
import collections
from nltk.corpus import words

# nltk.download("words")

# Creating a frequency Counter of all the words
frequency_counter = collections.Counter(df.posts.explode())
sorted_common_words = sorted(frequency_counter.items(), key = lambda pair: -pair[1])

words_lst = []
for i in range(len(sorted_common_words)):
    if sorted_common_words[i][1] > 1000:
        words_lst.append(sorted_common_words[i][0])

valid_words = []
invalid_words = []

valid_words = [word for word in words_lst if word in words.words()]
invalid_words = [word for word in words_lst if word not in words.words()]
```

My problem is that the `invalid_words` list is containing some valid English words like:

1. f*ck
2. changed
3. surprised
4. girlfriend
5. avatar
6. anymore

[image: word.words() check]

And some more of course. Even checking manually if those words exist in the `words.words()` it returns `False`. I tried initially to stem my text but this produced some root of the words, which didn't look right, and that's why decided to lemmatize them.

Is there a library in Python which have all the stemmed versions of the English words? I guess this will speed up significantly my script.

My original dataframe is around 9000 lines, and a bit more than 5M tokenized words and around 110.000 unique words after cleaning the dataset. 'words.words()`is containing 236736 words, so checking if those 110.000 words are within`words.words()` will take too much time. I have checked and checking of 1000 takes approximately a minute. This is mainly due to the limitation of Python to be run on only one core, so I cannot parallelize the operation on all available cores.

Comment: `in` will accurately report whether or not the string is in the collection. If it's saying false, the word isn't there, or it's in a different form than you're expecting (nested inside another list, or the word has whitespace in it).

Comment: yes, but I have used `.strip()` on my words and it is evident from the screenshot that for example "okay" without any spacing is missing from `words.words()

Comment: I just manually checked, the `words` does not contain any of those words. For the speed issue though, you can store the words in a `set` which allows for faster lookups.

Comment: But these are all valid words in English, plus I believe we need library of the stemmed forms of the words. This would be so much shorter, and faster. In addition, i am only checking the unique words who are on a list. Do you think that converting it to set will speed up things? What about list comprehension?

Comment: I can't answer why words are missing, because I have no experience with that library. For the performance though, a membership lookup of a set is much more efficient (roughly `O(1)`, compared to `O(n)` for a list lookup), and should be many, many times faster.

Comment: why not use an intersection of words the 2 sets? that are valid and those who are not valid based on the words.words()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this solution:

```
# your code as it was before
words_lst = []
for i in range(len(sorted_common_words)):
    if sorted_common_words[i][1] > 1000:
        words_lst.append(sorted_common_words[i][0])

import numpy as np

words_arr = np.array(words_lst,dtype=str)
words_dictionary = np.array(words.words(),dtype=str)

mask_valid_words = np.in1d(words_arr, words_dictionary)

valid_words = words_arr[mask_valid_words]
invalid_words = words_arr[~mask_valid_words]
```

Comment: this is indeed a super fast method. Thanks a lot for pointing it out to me.